# Is the Auslander-Reiten translation, restricted to non-projective and non-injective modules, exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, exact-sequence

I guess there should be a general category-theory answer to this question, but I'm asking what I'm interested in specifically, since I don't know if it is true:

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional hereditary algebra. Let $\tau = D \circ Tr: \text{mod}(H) \to \text{mod}(H)$ be the Auslander-Reiten translation and let $\tau^{-} = Tr \circ D: \text{mod}(H) \to \text{mod}(H)$ be the Auslander-Reiten translation in the other direction.

**Fact 1:** $\tau$ is a left exact additive functor, $\tau^-$ is a right exact additive functor.

**Fact 2:** Let $\text{mod}(H)_i$ be the category of finite-dimensional $H$-modules without indecomposable injective direct summands and $\text{mod}(H)_p$ be the category of finite-dimensional $H$-modules without indecomposable projective direct summands. Then $\tau: \text{mod}(H)_p \to \text{mod}(H)_i$ is an equivalence of categories with quasi-inverse $\tau^{-}$.

**Question:** Are $\tau$ and $\tau^-$, restricted as above, *exact*?

*Added after Jeremy's answer:* Is there also a proof which only uses the two facts stated by me and not the concrete definition of the Auslander-Reiten translation? So is this somehow just a category theory consequence?

Comment: Your title mentions (non-)preprojective and preinjective modules, but they don't seem to play a role in the question?

Comment: I'm sorry. Originally I thought it would be about non-preprojective (and non-preinjective) modules and while formulating the question I realized it is about non-projective and non-injective modules. I changed the title now.

Answer (score 7):

If $H$ is hereditary, then Auslander-Reiten translation is simply $\tau X=D\text{Ext}^1_H(X,H)$. Also, $\text{Ext}^2_H$ vanishes, and if $X$ has no nonzero projective direct summand then $\text{Hom}_H(X,H)=0$ since every submodule of $H$ is projective. [If $\alpha:X\to H$ is a non-zero map then $\text{im}(\alpha)$ is projective, so $X\to\text{im}(\alpha)$ splits, and so $X$ has a direct summand isomorphic to $\text{im}(\alpha)$.]

So if $0\to L\to M\to N\to 0$ is a short exact sequence of $H$-modules with no projective summands, the long exact $\text{Ext}$ sequence obtained by applying $\text{Hom}_H(-,H)$ reduces to
$$0\to\text{Ext}^1_H(N,H)\to\text{Ext}^1_H(M,H)\to\text{Ext}^1_H(L,H)\to0$$
and so, taking vector space duals, we get a short exact sequence
$$0\to\tau L\to\tau M\to\tau N\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question. Do you know if there is also an answer which only uses the two facts I stated? so is the exactness just a categorical corollary from the two facts? I'll edit my question in this regard.